# on click of folders should be inserted into the text box using node.js and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a file browser app.Here on click of a folder should be inserted into the text box provided.

Suppose if I click on app folder,I want the /app folder to be inserted into the provided text box.I've followed this [URL](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/how-to-create-a-web-based-file-browser-using-nodejs-express-and-jquery-datatables/) in order to make this file browser app.

[image]

My template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>File Browser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="panelDiv">

           <div class="panel-heading">
                   <button type="button" id="butDiv" >Browse</button>
                    <input type="text" name="location"/>
                   <span class="up">
                    <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i> Up
                   </span> 
           </div>
      <div id="showDiv" class="panel-body">
              <table class="linksholder">
              </table>
      </div>

  </div> 
    <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/datatable/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/app.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#butDiv").click(function(){
        $("#showDiv").toggle();

 });
});  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please suggest me regarding this issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jquery already I would say the easiest would set the jquery event click for the folders to select the text input element and use the `.val ()` function to set your new value so it would look something like this

```
$(".folder selector").click (function (){
    $(".textbox selector").val ("/"+this.text());
});
```

I'm not sure if the value function works on input elements but if not you could change it to a `<textarea></textarea>`